# Can "Don't be sad" start a sentence followed by a comma?

Tags: phrase-usage, syntax

Example sentence:

> Don't be sad, everything will turn out fine.

I've seen "Don't worry" used like this, so I think it's not ungrammatical. But part of me, sees "Don't be sad" as a complete sentence, so I'm a bit skeptic about this usage.

Maybe it's grammatically correct to start a sentence with an imperative sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English speech, the end of a sentence is indicated with a lowering of voice pitch.

Sometimes two closely related sentences are spoken one directly after another, and pitch is/would be lowered or lowered only very slightly.  A comma can be used instead of a period to mark this.

Have an English speaking friend, if possible, read the sentence to you with a comma and then with a period.